# Image not found issue in magento

Tags: magento

I have developed a custom module to catch events and trigger a particular observer, i used the above code to check if the image exists in the product it returns "Image not found error while saving the product is there any other way to check if the image exists ?. 
How can i fix the image not found issue?

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
if ($product->getImageUrl()) {
    //insert
}else{
    //update
}
```

Comment: in which page r u checking image exist or not?

Comment: Actually am checking this on observer.php but when i try to save the product it throws image not found error, if i comment this part of the code it works fine.

Comment: have you put image in media/import folder?

Comment: Yes, But if upload the image from the back-end it is not working and it shows image not found. It happens only if i use the above code, is there any alternative to check whether the product have image or not?

Comment: lets see what's available in the product, var_dump($product). I think the product collection didn't loaded.

Comment: The product collection is loaded( I have logged and everything is there ) and it fails while i am checking the product image exist or not.

Comment: so then you are using wrong method, try others ( check Magento doc )